# Deploying subdomain under flask and apache2

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualhost

Hi I am deploying a subdomain under my main domain "qianshan.co". When I enter the subdomain "m.qianshan.co" in the address line of browser, it appears the file directory of my project...(that is so embarrassing)

I followed several tutorials on Digital Ocean but it didn't work. There must something wrong with `__init__.py` and virtual host config. Tks so much!

Error: Enter subdomain and displays remote project directory:
[image]

**Here are my codes and directories:**

1. **init**.py

[image]

2. virtual host directory

[image]

3. virtual host config of main domain

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName qianshan.co
           ServerAdmin spark@qianshan.co
           WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/qianshan/qianshan.wsgi
           <Directory /var/www/qianshan/>
                   Order allow,deny
                   Allow from all
           </Directory>
           Alias /static /var/www/qianshan/static
           <Directory /var/www/qianshan/static/>
                   Order allow,deny
                   Allow from all
           </Directory>
           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           LogLevel warn
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. virtual host config of sub domain

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName m.qianshan.co
           ServerAdmin spark@qianshan.co
           DocumentRoot /var/www/qianshan
           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           LogLevel warn
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. DNS config
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem a Flask problem.

You have defined your base virtualhost with all the params needed but you forgot to copy alla of them in the other VH config.

Try to configure the m. subdomain as the main domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName m.qianshan.co
        ServerAdmin spark@qianshan.co
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/qianshan/qianshan.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/qianshan/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/qianshan/static
        <Directory /var/www/qianshan/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Every VH in Apache is a separate entity. They share only the global parameters which are defined **outside** the `VirtualHost` directives.

Comment: Hi Paolo, I edited the VH config as above and when I enter the m.subdomain in the address line, it returns the index page of the main domain. But actually in my __init__.py file, I want the server return the sentence "mobile site of qianshan under development". How am I able to make the sub domain return a different index page with the main domain?

Comment: This is a whole different problem. :)  You have 2 choices: (a) using a different project located in another path. (b) detect the domain when you need to discriminate on domain name. Using `request.host`

Comment: Tks, My initial purpose was actually differentiate the main domain and sub domain: providing different index page for them. i'll try as you suggested, thanks.